# Unicode functions for Lua

Tags: unicode, lua

Sorry if this has already been asked, but Lua's in-built string functions (such as `string.len` and `string.sub`) don't work very well with unicode characters, so are there any alternatives which do?

Comment: `function string.utf8len(s) return #s:gsub("[\128-\191]", "") end`

Comment: `function string.utf8sub(s, i, j) local len = #s:gsub("[\128-\191]", "") return s:gsub(".[\128-\191]*", "", i < 0 and len + i or i - 1):reverse():gsub("[\128-\191]*.", "", j and (j < 0 and -1 - j or len - j) or 0):reverse() end`

Answer (score 2):

There are various libraries available that do this, for example: https://github.com/alexander-yakushev/awesompd/blob/master/utf8.lua. Also, Lua 5.3+ supports some of utf8-related functions out of the box: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.5